# Error When Creating Search Index in Cassandra Enterprise (DSE)

Tags: indexing, solr, cassandra, datastax-enterprise

I'm trying to create a search index on my table in DSE 6.8. This is my table in the test keyspace:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
   username text,
   first_name text,
   last_name text,
   password text,
   email text,
   last_access timeuuid,
   PRIMARY KEY(username));
```

I tried this query:

```
CREATE SEARCH INDEX ON test.users;
```

and this is the response:

```
InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Search statements are not supported on this node"
```

I think there must be something that I should change in some file for DSE to support search statements. I've already set the `SOLR_ENABLED` in `/etc/default/dse` to 1. I'm totally new to this and I don't know if there's something wrong with my table or anything else.

can anyone suggest what might be causing this error? Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you restarted DSE after changing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message suggests, you can only [create a Search index](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.8/cql/cql/cql_reference/cql_commands/cqlCreateSearchIndex.html) on DSE nodes running in Search mode.

Check the node's workload by running the command below. It will tell you if the node is running in pure Cassandra mode or Search mode.

```
$ dsetool status
```

If you have installed [DSE using the binary tarball](https://docs.datastax.com/en/install/6.8/install/installTARdse.html), it doesn't use `/etc/default/dse`. Instead [start DSE as a standalone process](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.8/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/operations/startStop/startDseStandalone.html) with the `-s` flag to start it in Search mode:

```
$ dse cassandra -s
```

Cheers!